# How do I make an ascending function in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to make a simple function in c++ that will say if an entered integer has its digits ascending from left to right. Ex, 123 is ascending. We just started learning recurssion, which is what I'm supposed to use, but I'm confused. So far what I was thinking is that you store the last digit as a temp, then compare that to the next digit, but how would you manage to do that?

```
bool ascending(int n) {
    int temp = n % 10;
    while (n / 10 > 0) {
        n = n / 10;
        if (temp > n % 10) {
            return false;
            break;
        }
        temp = n % 10;
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far, but I'm definitely messing up. I'm not even using recurrsion.

Comment: Please share your code here then we can help you in easy way

Comment: Recursion is about specifying a problem in terms of a simpler problem.  In your case, the simpler problem is probably going to be a number with one less digit.  So think about how to specify the problem that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can go about it.

On every iteration, you check that last 2 digits are in order. And when the number is a single digit, return `true`

```
bool ascending(int n) {
    int last_digit = n % 10;
    int remainder = n / 10;

    if (remainder == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    int second_last_digit = remainder % 10;
    if (last_digit < second_last_digit)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return ascending(remainder); // Recusrive call
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the second return be true? Because doesn't that say if the last digit is less than the second to last, it's false? But wouldn't that make it descending and not ascending?

Comment: The example above works from the last digit, so we want the last digit to be greater than the second last digit for the whole number to be in ascending order

Comment: Oh man, I read that completley wrong, you're right. Thank you!

Comment: short version: `return !value || (value % 10 >= value / 10 % 10 ? is_ascending(value / 10) : false);`